# Performance rsync usb on RPI

Tags: hard-drive, usb, raid, rsync, raspberry-pi

I don't know if this is the correct place to ask this question, but here I am.

I'm planning to create my own NAS using a RPI. The issue is that it is really difficult to have good performance using RAID with 2 USB HDD. Then I was thinking on using rsync and synchronized the 2 HDD during night hours. The 2 HDD will be 2TB.

And here my question, what is the performance of rsync on such a big volume of data through USB 2.0? When using low data volumes it's ok, but I don't know as I'm increasing the amount of it. Let's say I will put picture, documents, etc. and most of them are not gonna change a lot.

TA.

Answer (score 0):

The performance depends on the usb 2.0. The maximum transfer speed is:
60 MByte/s and average 12 mb per seconds in real life.

Comment: How did you calculate that "real life" average, not knowing which exact HDDs will be used and what the composition of small (I/O needed) and large (sequential speed needed)  will be?